# Is every graph with maximum degree k a subgraph of some graph with minimum degree k?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $S_0$ be the set of all graphs with $\Delta(g) = k$ and n vertices and $S_1$ be the set of all graphs with $\delta(g) = k$ also with n vertices. Is it true that for all $b \in S_1$ there exits $a \in S_0$ such that A is a subgraph of B?

Comment: There is a theorem which says every graph with maximum degree $\Delta$ is a subgraph of a $\Delta-regular$ graph. As in every $k-regular$ graph we have $\Delta=\delta=k$ then the answer is obvious.

Comment: @C.B Thanks for the info!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B\in S_1$, remove edges from all the vertices $v\in V(B)$, where $d(v)>k\;$ till the degree of any vertex is at most $k$.

The given graph is in $S_0$, also it is spanning subgraph of $B$.

Comment: What you've shown is that every graph $A \in S_0$ is a subgraph of some graph in $S_1$ which does not answer the question.

Comment: @Budge I have modified my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I agree that the subgraph generated in this way will have maximum degree $k$. However, I'm unconvinced that this subgraph will span B. Do you have a proof of this fact?

Comment: @Budge Yes, because  the produced graph have the same number of vertices, and its edges are in that of  $B$.

Comment: All of the edges are definitely in $B$ but I'm not sure that it will have the same number of vertices. I'm concerned that removing edges in the manner you described might lead to "disconnecting" a vertex from the graph.

Comment: @Budge There is no condition in the question that states that the graphs in $S_0$ and $S_1$ should be connected. If so the answer will be no.

Comment: You're right. My bad. I was interested in only connected graphs but failed to mention that. Thank you!